# Prove that $\overline{\ln(\frac{c}{\overline{z}}+d)}=\ln(\frac{c}{z}+d)$

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms

Prove that $\overline{\ln(\frac{c}{\overline{z}}+d)}=\ln(\frac{c}{z}+d)$

My attempt; first note that $z=re^{i\theta}$ thus $\frac{1}{\overline{z}}=z$ now substituting this into the lhs of what we are trying to prove we get the desired result, noting that since $c,d \in \Bbb R $ there signs do not change.

Here I'm talking about the principal branch of the logarithm. Could anyone tell me if this is correct ?

Comment: Have you tried $c=0, d=-1$, where the principal value gives you different answers for the two sides?

Comment: Is this not asking whether $\overline{\ln(\overline{z})}=\ln({z})$ ? @GEdgar 's counterexample then becomes $z=-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that [$\overline{\ln z}=\ln\overline z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2689857/505767) then

$$\overline{\ln\left(\frac{c}{\overline{z}}+d\right)}=\ln\left(\overline{\frac{c}{\bar z}+d}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{c}{z}+d\right)$$