# Conjugate of complex number raised to complex power

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Why is $\overline{z^{n}} = (\bar{z})^{n}$ true only for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$? What about a real or complex exponent in general?

Let $$\log z=\{\ln \rho + i (\theta + 2k\pi)\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$$

then
$$
\overline{\log z} = \overline{\ln \rho + i (\theta + 2k\pi)} = \ln \rho - i (\theta + 2k\pi) = \ln \rho + i (-\theta + 2k\pi) = \log \bar{z}
$$
So, let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, then
$$
\overline{z^{\alpha}} = \overline{e^{\alpha \log z}} = e^{\bar{\alpha} \log \bar{z}} = (\bar{z})^{\bar{\alpha}}
$$
It seems than the integer exponent is a particular case of a more general property. Did I make some mistake in my proof?

Edit: My question is twofold. Is the first equality about conjugate of the log correct? And if it is, is the second one about the conjugate of $z^\alpha$ correct? Maybe I am doing something wrong and I'll be glad if somebody could point out where are my mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: Your $z^\alpha:=e^{\alpha\log z}$ is multivalued if $\alpha\notin\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, but I don't get why being multivalued makes it wrong. It seems true for every value. And what about the principal value? Is it true then?

Comment: Your post is not very clear. By "With $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (I am not choosing a branch, everything goes) I have
$
\log z=\ln \rho + i (\theta + 2k\pi)$",  you mean $
\log z=\{\ln \rho + i (\theta + 2k\pi)\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$, don't you? With such an (unsual!) definition of $z^\alpha$, I agree with your equalities of *sets of* complex numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\overline{\ln z}=\ln\overline z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689857/prove-that-overline-ln-z-ln-overline-z)

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I mean I consider the sets of all the values, but as the answer you posted showed that even if you limit yourself to a particular value for the log (in that case the principal value) then it is also true that $\overline{\ln(z)}=\ln(\bar{z})$. So my question stand, where is my mistake? And what about the second part of the question? Is my reasoning wrong given the first part about the log? (By the way why do you consider my definition unusual? It is how I was taught the complex log and showed that it has infinite possible values.

Comment: I see no mistake . What is unusual (at least for me) was not $\log$ but, as I said, your definition of $z^\alpha$. I thought it was never defined because it has no good properties.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your help. What is your definition of $z^{\alpha}$? I would like to see how it affects my "proof".

Comment: Sorry to not help that much. As I said, I thought there was none, but if I take yours I found no mistake in your post.

Comment: @AnneBauval Don't be sorry, you already helped me a lot. I will wait to see if someone post an answer. Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Can you say where the first sentence comes from, especially the "true _only_ for..." assertion?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I just looked at the wikipedia page of complex conjugate and saw that formula for $n$ integer. It wasn't explicity written that it was valid only for integers but I assumed so. Do you think it could be true?

Comment: (i) The identity "$\overline{z^n} = \bar{z}^n$ for all non-zero complex $z$" is true for integer $n$ (and for $z = 0$ if $n$ is non-negative, though we can surely start a hot argument about whether "$0^0=1$" ;). (ii) As @AnneBauval confirms, your argument shows that if we suitably interpret a complex power expression as multi-valued, then "$\overline{z^n} = \bar{z}^n$ for all non-zero complex $z$" holds for all real $n$. <> Is that what you're asking? "Do you think it could be true?" reads ambiguously to me here.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for your help. Yes, I was asking exactly that. What about single value complex power? Should I consider a $z$ not equals to a negative real number in that case?

Answer (score 1):

If we consider $z^\alpha$ to be a multivalued function - in particular "$z^\alpha$" does not represent a complex number, but rather a set of complex numbers, then, yes, $\overline {z^\alpha} = {\overline z}^{\overline \alpha}$ holds. But we have to be careful about what exactly we mean by it.

If $z = \rho e^{i\theta} = \rho e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)}$ for all $k\in \Bbb Z$, and $\alpha = x + iy$, then $$z^\alpha = \{\rho^xe^{-y(\theta + 2k\pi)}e^{i(y\ln \rho + x(\theta + 2k\pi))} : k \in \Bbb Z\}$$
$$\overline{z^\alpha} = \{\rho^xe^{-y(\theta + 2k\pi)}e^{-i(y\ln \rho + x(\theta + 2k\pi))} : k \in \Bbb Z\}$$
while $${\overline z}^{\overline\alpha} = \{\rho^xe^{-(-y)(-\theta - 2k\pi)}e^{i((-y)\ln \rho + x(-\theta - 2k\pi))} : k \in \Bbb Z\}$$
Since $(-y)(-\theta - 2k\pi) = y(\theta + 2k\pi)$ and $i((-y)\ln \rho + x(-\theta - 2k\pi)) = -i(y\ln \rho + x(\theta + 2k\pi))$. The two sets are the same. Everything that is in one is in the other. I.e., $\overline{z^\alpha} = {\overline z}^{\overline\alpha}$ is actually a statement about set equality, not value equality.

But the reason most sources will tell you that this holds for general $z$ only when $\alpha \in \Bbb Z$ is that they are **not** defining $z^\alpha$ as a multi-valued function. Instead they are using a "branch-cut" definition, making it a single-valued expression. For each $z, \alpha$ you establish some means (the "branch-cut") of assigning a specific member of the set $\{\rho^xe^{-y(\theta + 2k\pi)}e^{i(y\ln \rho + x(\theta + 2k\pi))} : k \in \Bbb Z\}$ to be the value of $z^\alpha$. It can be proven that only when $\alpha \in \Bbb Z$ is it possible to establish a branch cut which gives the same value for $\overline{z^\alpha}$ and ${\overline z}^{\overline\alpha}$ for all $z$.